# Extending HttpErrorResponse leads to error Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'

Tags: angular, angular8, electron-builder

I have a model (defined in separate file) which extends HttpErrorResponse with custom property. Custom property is an interface with few properties:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface ApiErrorBody {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  message?: string;
  trace?: string;
}

export class ApiErrorResponse extends HttpErrorResponse {
  public error: ApiErrorBody;
}
```

This code works fine in debug mode, but when compiling to prod, I see error at runtime:

> Error: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'

If I remove extension and just populate the same properties as HttpErrorResponse has, code works fine in prod, but I need to keep extension syntax.

```
export interface ApiErrorBody {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  message?: string;
  trace?: string;
}

// no extension
export class ApiErrorResponse {
  public error: ApiErrorBody;
  public status: number;
  public message: string;
  piblic url: string;
}
```

This model is referenced from multiple components and interceptors and all of them are provided with dependency on @angular/common/http, so my questions are - what else I missed here and why it works in debug but doesn't work in prod mode?

Comment: When does it fail at runtime? If there's errors in the console, provide pictures of those.

Comment: It's actually hosted in Electron application and when I start the app I see following error message: http://prntscr.com/stih93

Comment: What is your angular version? Older angular versions use [`@angular/http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/http)

Comment: Then it might be an electron specific problem, but I don't have any knowledge of that. You could try to run your project on a `http-server` in production mode and see if it works there. I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in package.json
Package @angular/common was in devDependencies. According to documentation of Electron builder (https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) dev dependencies never copied to resulting package.

Moving dependencies that start with "@angular" to dependencies from devDependencies section in package.json solved the issues.